# Comma and Clauses?

Tags: phrases

I have a quick question!

Why is there no comma before "but"? I thought the phrase "your body can't make them", is an independant clause? I would really appreciate help with this. Does it not express a full idea, and if so, how do I tell?

"That means they're required for normal body functions but your body can't make them."

Thanks guys!

Comment: In some cases, like this one, placing or not placing commas is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: How can you know what cases that it's up to personal preference? Thank you for your help

Comment: That's a broad topic. I hope it's covered somewhere else on this site, but I can't find the question right now.

Comment: Think of 'and' in place of 'but'. 'But' is a coordinating  conjunction and may be used without a comma before it. "Although she was tired, she went to work. = She was tired but she went to work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "That means they're required for normal body functions but your body can't make them."

It may be a matter of style as to using or not using commas here, but, it may also be a matter of helping the reader understand the intent of the sentence.
If speaking, one might pause before or after "but" to indicate the joining of two thoughts. I would isolate "but" this way:

> "That means they're required for normal body functions, but, your body can't make them."

so there is no question that two thoughts are being joined. There is disagreement about use of commas, so there can be no absolute "rule" here.
To me, this:

> "That means they're required for normal body functions, but your body can't make them."

is also good.
As a "rule", I would prefer to be questioned by a grammarian than to risk being misunderstood.